# Parsing complex json data in Flutter

Tags: json, list, parsing, flutter, request

we are new in Flutter. In a point at our Project we have to post a request and it should return a text and an attachement(Link with action, fett kursiv...) if there is one, for the text it works very well, but the attachement doesn't, the attachement as written under is a List. How could we get in the response the attachement as well? Thank you.

the Body response :

```
[
{
    "requestText": null,
    "text": "Hey, what kann I do for you?",
    "accessToken": null,
    "attachments": [{          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "LINK",
            "filename": "",
            "job": "",
            "title": "transfer to Yahoo",
            "action": "Zu Google",
            "video": null,
            "link": "https://www.yahoo.com",
            "accordionText": "",
            "datePickerRange": "",
            "mediaType": null,
            "multipleChoiceOptions": null
        },],
    "action": null,
    "activeBot": null,
  #  "messageKey": null,
    "error": false
}
```

]

Our working Code but only for text:

```
  Future<Botresp> createAlbum(String text) async {

final http.Response response1 = await http.post(
  '(private Link....)',
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'historyID' : 'dsdsadsadasdasddsds',
    'username':  'test',
  },
  body: jsonEncode({
    "text": '${text}' ,
  }),
);
final jsonresponse = json.decode(response1.body);
if (response1.statusCode == 200) {
  print(jsonresponse[0]);
  return Botresp.fromJson(jsonresponse[0]);
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to create...');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `Botresp` should define a `List<Attachment>` to store your attachments. The `Attachment` class could look like this:

```
class Attachment {
  String name;
  // add the rest of the fields here

  Attachment({this.name});

  factory Attachment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Attachment(
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
  }

  static List<Attachment> fromJsonList(List json) {
    List<Attachment> attachments =
        json.map((attachment) => Attachment.fromJson(attachment)).toList();
    return attachments;
  }
}
```

And then in your `Botresp.fromJson` use `Attachment.fromJsonList` to parse it into your `List<Attachment>`.